# Define owl carousel with data attribute in magnific popup callbacks function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup, owl-carousel-2

I have implement **Owl carousel** in **Magnific Popup**. and, It is normaly working fine. if, I have use simple function `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({autoplay:true, items:1})`

but, **Owl carousel does not work when i define Owl carousel with data attribute.**

HTML:

```
<a class="ajax-popup btn btn-dark" href="ajaxproject.html">Click To Open Popup</a>
```

**ajaxproject.html** file:

```
<div class="container ajax-container">
  <h2 class="text-7 text-center mb-4">Title 1</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-autoplay="true" data-items="1">
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="images/bg/image-6.jpg"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="images/bg/image-5.jpg"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <h4 class="text-4 font-weight-600">Description:</h4>
      <p>Lisque persius interesset his et, in quot quidam persequeris vim, ad mea essent possim iriure. Lisque persius interesset his et, in quot quidam persequeris vim, ad mea essent possim iriure.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Define owl carousel with data attribute:** But, this is not working. What is wrong here?

```
$(".ajax-popup").magnificPopup({
    type: "ajax",
    mainClass: "mfp-fade",
    closeBtnInside: true,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {

            $(".owl-carousel").each(function (index) {
                var items = $(this).data('slides');
                var autoplay = $(this).data('autoplay');
                $(this).owlCarousel({
                    items: items,
                    autoplay: autoplay
                });
            });

         }
    }
});
```

**It is working fine. if I have use Define owl carousel without data attribute:**

```
$(".ajax-popup").magnificPopup({
    type: "ajax",
    mainClass: "mfp-fade",
    closeBtnInside: true,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {

           $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
               autoplay:true,
               items:1
           })

         }
    }
});
```

Comment: So do you want images in owl-carousel to popup using magnific-popup? Can you provide a "working" example including html and css from magnific-popup.

Comment: @KalimahApps Yes, I want Owl-carsousel load in magnific-popup. It is working fine if I use `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({autoplay:true, items:1})` this in callbacks function. but, it does not work if I have use Define owl carousel with data attribute according to mention question. Here, I have update my question. Please check again. Hope, You are understand my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access data-* attributes you need to use `.attr()` not `.data()`. Your code should be:

```
$(".ajax-popup").magnificPopup({
    type: "ajax",
    mainClass: "mfp-fade",
    closeBtnInside: true,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {

            $(".owl-carousel").each(function (index) {
                var items = $(this).attr('data-items');
                var autoplay = $(this).attr('data-autoplay');
                $(this).owlCarousel({
                    items: items,
                    autoplay: autoplay
                });
            });

         }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is working now. You was defined `slides` instead of `items` in your code. i have update your answer. Thanks you so much.

Comment: No problems. I realized the issues but I thought that's what you had in your code. Good to know its workin